# Ethernet interface not detected during CentOS 6 installation

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet

I'm trying to install CentOS 6 on a a Dell Inspiron 14z 5423 but cannot get it to detect the wired network interface.

Here's what happens:

- Begin installation with CentOS Minimal CD and go through the wizard
- At the page asking for the Hostname, there's a "Configure Network" button
- Clicking on it opens the "Network Connections" dialogue box, showing "System wlan0", for the wireless interface, but nothing else. There is an "Add" button, but I don't know what the MAC address is, and whether that would even work.

I suspect that this is a driver issue? Is there a generic driver I could try, and if so, how would I go about it?

By the way, I previously had CentOS 7 and the Ethernet port worked fine. I specifically want CentOS 6 for testing purposes.

If somebody could outline a procedure to resolve this, or point me in the right direction, will be much appreciated. I have searched and looked at various other posts, such as https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7684, but they did not help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is a driver issue: kernel version in CentOS 6 is too old and doesn't have a driver for your NIC. To verify, use [this page](https://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/) or a similar one: upload your `lspci -n` output and see which driver supports your NIC and in what version did the support appear. Check [git log for the driver's subdirectory](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet) in linux-stable sources if you are unsure.

Since only things Kenshi Muto's HCL page is interested in are VID and PID of PCI devices, you could simulate the `lspci -n` output closely enough using only bash and sysfs:

```
for d in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*; do
 vid=$(cat $d/vendor)
 pid=$(cat $d/device)
 echo "${vid#*x}:${pid#*x}"
done
```

One of the ways of solving the "driver is absent due to kernel being too old" issue is installing a newer kernel from [ElRepo](http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php) once the system is installed. Since you can't add a network repo to your system without network access, you can circumvent the Catch-22 by downloading the appropriate RPM with new kernel from http://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el6/ (follow the link with your machine arcitecture (`i386` or `x86_64`), then `RPMS`), copy it on a thumbdrive and install using `rpm -ivh <file>.rpm`. Choose between `kernel-ml-<version>` (built from mainline sources, newer, but more chances to contain bugs) and `kernel-lt-<version>` (built from "long term support" sources, older, but more stable). You probably won't need the `-doc` package, though you might need `-firmware` (see below) or `-devel`/`-headers` if you have some drivers which should be built locally from sources (like VirtualBox). Download them, too.

Another, but less probable cause might be the firmware which is required to be loaded at runtime by the driver for NIC to be operational. Check `dmesg` output for errors about looking for, but not finding `/lib/firmware/...` files. When installing CentOS, `/lib/firmware` resides on a ramdisk, so it should be possible to download files from [linux-firmware repo](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) on a thumbdrive, plug it, `mount` and `cp` the files to the required location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It's useful but didn't get a chance to try them yet because this is a minimal CentOS installation. lspci is not available. And without a network connection would be difficult to install a new Kernel. I guess I'll have to either get stuff from a new machine or download and prepare some media with full CentOS 6.

Comment: @Nagev, Since only things Kenshi Muto's HCL page is interested in are VID and PID of PCI devices, you could provide it using bash and sysfs (I hope both of these are available even in minimal CentOS installer): `for d in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*; do vid=$(cat $d/vendor); pid=$(cat $d/device); echo "${vid#*x}:${pid#*x}"; done`

Comment: Nice, that page showed that indeed was a driver issue like we suspected: "19691090 Yes Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet alx v3.16.0-" . The kernel present was 2.6.x, so I downloaded and installed 4.9.8. I can see that the driver is now loaded when I do "dmesg | grep eth". I'm still getting the "Device ETH0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization." Even after doing something like this: http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/configure-centos-6-network-settings/ . Anyway, that's another issue, which I'll sort out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK after a bit of experimentation, no luck bringing the interface up. Searched for the "eth0 device does not seem to be present" issue, but it seems for everyone doing a clone of a VM was the cause, and deleting the *persistent-net.rules file or fixing the MAC address is the answer. Not in my case.

I am considering the possibility that this kernel, while correctly loading the driver, is somehow not compatible with CentOS 6. So for anyone going down this path, there's no guarantee of success. But it was worth a try for me.

Comment: @Nagev, so you don't see the interface in `ip link` output and thus it's not possible to even run the appropriate `ip addr add ...`/`ip route add ...`/`echo ... > /etc/resolv.conf` or `dhclient eth0` manually (for testing purposes)? Are there any errors surrounding NIC-related lines in `dmesg` output?

Comment: I do see it, problem was I couldn't bring it up using ifup, or making changes and restarting network service. I would get a "Device ETH0 not present..." message. But, dhclient eth0 works! It's up and has an IP address. Thanks!

Comment: @Nagev, network interface names are case-sensitive: `ETH0` isn't same as `eth0` (and the former is probably wrong). For dhcp, filling /etc/sysconfig/{network,network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0} as shown at http://pastebin.com/2xJZ6Ta7 should be enough; detailed examples of static and dhcp configurations are available at https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6?highlight=%28networking%29#head-7bc680c9bc8e13dadf1eb55e3a31dd7c055ae1bb

Comment: I know it's case sensitive, it was a typo! Shouldn't have been multi-tasking... was so sure in my mind I had typed it lower case, I was under the impression the message capitalized it and it didn't even occur to me to check ifcfg-eth0, you were right! Anyway, fixed it, all good now.